# C++ boost prevents from showing main window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, boost, directx

I got really weird problem here. I'm creating pretty simple 2d game engine in C++/DirectX and I wanted to use boost (particularly boost serialization). The problem is, when I put the simplest boost example into my code and build the project, the window (created in winapi) is not visible. There are no problems during compilation and the strangest part - boost serialization works well (saves simple string into the file). I tried different things, I even reinstalled boost but the problem still remains. The error seems to be within this line:

```
text_oarchive oa(ofs);
```

When I uncomment it the windows is visible. Anyone came across this kind of problem? I really need those boost libraries...

Comment: Could you post a minimal example with code that demonstrates your problem? More info on the development environment you are using would be benefitial.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 10. I tried very simple code: `code`std::ofstream file("archive.txt"); 
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(file); 
  std::string s = "Hello World!\n"; 
  oa << s;`code` Even this simple code doesn't work. I tried to move it around my code but the effect is still the same.